# Were Jem'Hedar always genetically engineered?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Did the Founders create them from scratch or did they 'corrupt' a species that once bred naturally?

Answer (score 7):

The [*Memory Beta* entry for the Jem'Hadar](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Jem%27Hadar) implies, but does not directly state, that the Jem'Hadar were found and genetically altered by the Founders, rather than being created from scratch. In the language and history sub-headings the Jem'Hadar are referred to as developing their own language prior to contact with the Founders.

The citation is unclear, however; it seem to be information from a Roleplaying game known as *[Decipher](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Decipher_RPG)*. The canonicity of this, much like all *Star Trek* material that is untelevised, is questionable.

This does fit, however, with what we know of Changeling genetic science; the Vorta were known to have been altered from their original arboreal nature to serve the Founders, in gratitude for sheltering a wounded Founder from a mob on their homeworld, where they were obviously not the dominant species. So *Memory Beta*'s information, while speculative, seems likely to be the case.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. While not 100% this is the most likely case.

Comment: The founders don't appear to have the abilities to actually created a sentient species from scratch so its a safe bet that they were just genetically engineered from an existing species. had the founders been closer to the Klingons they would have been a great choice for the tetracel white.